# Connecting ZeroMQ from browser to server

Tags: javascript, python, multiprocessing, zeromq

I am trying to get ZeroMQ working in my web app. On the front end, I am using the JSZMQ library which is supposed to work in-browser (I am aware that most libraries do not). On the Python back end, I am using zmq. The problem is that all the protocols I try throw an error. If I try TCP, as expected the browser throws an error saying "unsupported transport".

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229933/send-data-from-browser-side-to-zeromq-node-js-client-server) JSZMQ should work when the protocol is "ws://". When I try this, the server throws a "Protocol not supported" error immediately on running it. Here is my code:

Client:

```js
import * as zmq from 'jszmq'

const socket = new zmq.Pull()
socket.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:3000')
socket.on('message', msg => console.log(msg))
```

Server:

```py
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
sock = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
sock.bind('ws://127.0.0.1:3000') # This is what throws the error
sock.send('hello')
```

If it matters I am doing multiprocessing for the server, with the zmq object as a global since it's not serializable and can't be passed into functions as an argument.

Why is this not working?

Comment: are you using a front-end framework?

Comment: Yes, I am using React and executing the code in the componentDidMount function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are a little confused here:

```
ws:// means http:// or default port 80
wss:// means https:// or default port 443

ws://<server>:<port> means http over that port.
```

What happens in background is that browser connect to the server over http(s) protocol and upgrade the connection to websocket if it's possible.

Browsers don't allow **Raw** socket connections, but **Websocket** ones.

Take a look at https://github.com/zeromq/jszmq#compatibility-with-zeromq :

> ### Compatibility with ZeroMQ
>
> WebSocket transport added to zeromq recently, and it is only available
> when compiling from source.
>
> Other ports of zeromq, like NetMQ (C#) and JeroMQ (Java) don't yet
> support the WebSocket transport.

You must take a look at [FastAPI Python Framework](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/).

The pattern that you are looking for would be:

```
[SOCKET CLIENT] --> [FASTAPI SERVER] <--> [ZEROMQ]
```

This documentation shows how to setup in a single file client websocket and FastAPI server:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/

Your job will be done between websocket.receive_text and websocket.send_text.

```
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()
        # --> ZeroMQ Code Here <--
        await websocket.send_text(f"Message text was: {data}")
```

This framework is so awesome that you can take much more advantage with native Background Tasks:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/

So, you can accept messages from client and send back when it has been done by some ZeroMQ worker.

There are a lot of features that are useful too, like Async Databases, Instant OpenAPI Documentation and so on.